# RESTful API - Caching Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, rest

I'm working on a RESTful Api - Web Page Client.

I have this problem: I have a constant request, I must do the request again and again trough the pages. Always the SAME / STATIC short answer (less than 10 elements). But it's a constant request in multiple pages. It is a request each time, and go to database each time. So, what about cache the data in the Web Page and avoid the request several times?

Is it ok? or is a bad idea? Have a better/different solution?

Implementation Details: I'm working with Rails & Angular.

My idea is a general service.

`dataService.get():
 - If I have the data. I return it.
 - If I haven't the data. Go to server, store it (to reuse) and then return it.`

Extra 0: The information ALMOST NEVER changes. In the worst case it only can change with the change of the API.

Extra 1: I have others BIG DATA requests. And I don't know what to do with it? Is ok to have the whole static data as a BIG json in Front-End or it must be in Back-End?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If it never changes, of course let the client know it can cache it. If it can change then it becomes a bit more complicated.

Comment: The information ALMOST NEVER changes. In the worst case it only can change with the change of the API. Those are Rails Enums. I Will add this in the question. Thanks @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: Hi José, I think this article might help you: https://www.themarketingtechnologist.co/caching-http-requests-in-angularjs/

Comment: Let me read it. Thanks @Leonardo.